# How come files become so incredibly large in Blender

Tags: blend-files, file-format

We are putting together a pretty large scene, approx 1km x 1km.
On it we are placing piping and other industrial equipment.
The question is how come a simple steel pipe of approx 1m diameter and 12 meters long with some textures comes in at over 150MB? There must be something we are doing wrong. I write this, because the elements we have built and want to populate our large scene with come in at over a 1GB to start with, which is crazy and we obviously must be doing something terribly wrong.
What do we need to do to drastically improve file size and optimize objects with textures?
I'll add the link of the file, so maybe somebody could have a quick look and tell us how to improve this. In our example, we need to make 100s and 100s of these pipes linked together...

Here's the link to our sample pipe with textures:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uRKtmXMbQK7SgIb_dAkG8FQ4CeqDuXa1/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much.

Comment: You pipe is unnecessarily subdivided and has a needlessly dense mesh

Comment: Hello. Not sure why your question was closed "off-topic". The pipe has 1.1 million faces. Do you need so many faces for a simple pipe? If I decimate the faces to 8000 the file size shrinks to 1.6 MB.

Comment: It looks like that the UV map alone takes about 50 MB of the file size. My PC can't handle this and just freezes. When I delete the UV map the file size is reduced to 96 MB.

Comment: Thank you very much for your terrific help!